# How to insert .dwf into an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to insert a .dwf file into an SSRS report.  I can get .jpg to work but when I try the .dwf I get these messages.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS isn't able to open Autodesk/.dwf files - both errors are the result of the application's inability to read them. More [here from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240150(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I had thought but was hoping I was wrong.  Thanks again.